# Control of a time-variant system

Tags: control, control-system

I am working in a control project in which I need to control two variables \$x\$ 
and \$y\$ according to their reference values.

Since I don't have an advanced knowledge in modern control theory, I usually 
tackle these problems using PI, PID, lead/lag controllers.

I have simplified my problem in the following image. My system has a matrix with 
time varying coefficients (and it adds coupling to the variables), and I am not 
being able to write the open-loop transfer function to find the good parameters 
of my PI controllers.

[image]

Do I need to use a fancier control structure than PI control or can I obtain an 
approximation of the transfer function and keep the topology of this solution?

Comment: The time varying matrix, I think you may need to explain with a little more detail, The visual I have on my head would be to just plot the correction vector for the proportional response of both outputs vs both inputs on a 2D graph to reverse out the transfer function.

Comment: This time varying matrix is actually a rotation matrix \begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix} with \$\theta = \omega t\$.

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to control, this seems like an odd approach, I'm left wondering if its an X-Y problem, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is a very specific problem, but I am trying to suppress some harmonics from an electrical motor according to https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8481417 and https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6780706. In order to identify these harmonics, the variables (currents in dq model) need to go through this rotation matrix with the respective frequency \$\omega\$ of the harmonics.

Comment: This seems to be a rundown on what your looking for, It is a bit beyond my normal control systems knowledge, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.703.3389&rep=rep1&type=pdf It mainly looks like they are using a variation of FFT to get the phase and frequency information and apply corrections in the frequency domain.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they do. Thank you for the article!